# How can I deal with an moderator trolling a question?

Tags: discussion, moderators

I've posted a question that a moderator decided to make a hobby horse out of. He left a response that I will not call an answer because it ignored the question and instead just focused on a *variable* that I had defined not being a standard CSS color. The only other commenter on the question noted that this was obvious and I've been doing my best to ignore it because I believe you should not feed the trolls.

Now, the moderator was rude to the only other commenter who was actually addressing the question I asked and making suggestions to help me and he has since left the discussion due to the harassment.

I've flagged the moderator's response as not an answer and asked that it be deleted but, I assume because this person is a moderator, the non-answer has not been deleted. How can I get the non-answer deleted? It's not helpful at all and it's just creating drama that is driving away people who would like to address the real question.

Comment: Are you talking about this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25370207/stylus-how-can-i-change-the-color-on-an-element-when-it-has-an-additional-class

Comment: @Mysticial, yup. That's the one.

Comment: Unless some comments were deleted, I don't see how the moderator was in any way rude.

Comment: @Mysticial Didn't you know that posting an answer that doesn't solve your problem is super rude?

Comment: *grabs popcorn...*

Comment: Yeah @Mysticial - it looks like another poster, someone not the moderator, was a little more testy.

Comment: You're doing the wrong thing by flagging an answer because you don't like it. That isn't what flagging is for. Vote it down, and get on with your life.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's clear this got to you and you're frustrated with the situation. Take a step back, don't engage the issue at all - neither here or with the moderator on the original question.

It **doesn't matter** whether or not anyone else agrees with any behavior on *either* side of the issue. You've already flagged the answer and said your piece. Rallying troops is, at best, pointless escalation - it will only serve to draw the conflict on longer. And if anything is driving away people who would help with the original question, it's the conflict - not some dude's wrong answer.

You alone have the power to move on.

Answer (score 30):

Not an answer flags are for answers that don't attempt to answer the question at all.  They are not for answers that attempt to answer the question but fail to do so for some reason.

If you feel that the answer is incorrect, or doesn't help you solve your problem, you are free to downvote it and optionally comment on the post explaining why it doesn't solve your problem.

While you are of course entirely within your rights to ignore someone who gives an incorrect answer as a result of a mis-understanding of the question, it is usually far more productive to either explain to them what it is about the question that they appear to not understand, or better still, to edit the question to remove the confusion entirely by adding additional information or clarifying what is currently there.  There is of course no need to address any user directly when doing so.

In this specific case it appears that you omitted a part of your project that indicates why this answer is incorrect.  Editing the question to include this detail would improve the question and help others trying to answer it, while also making it clear to this answerer why his answer doesn't solve the problem, allowing him to either edit it to account for this difference or to remove it entirely if he is unable to.

Answer (score 20):

This is [the answer you flagged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25370264/19679):

> > Each of these styles works on their own.
>
> I doubt it, since `yelloworange` [isn’t a CSS colour](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-color/#named-colors). If you look
>   at Stylus’s rendered CSS, you’ll see that it doesn’t recognize the
>   colour either (Stylus would have transformed it to its hex
>   representation).
>
> If you did have `yelloworange` defined as a custom value, make sure
>   you still do!

That is indeed an answer, or at least an attempt to address part of the question asked. You might not agree with it, or think it solves your problem, but that's not worthy of being flagged. I see no reason at all to summarily delete that.

If a moderator left a non-answer, and was flagged for it, I wouldn't hesitate to remove it as needed. Heck, I've deleted [my own non-answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170067/link-only-answer-should-be-flagged/170068#170068) after having them flagged. We handle flags on each other all the time.

Also, I wouldn't qualify someone trying to help you out with a polite answer as "trolling".

Comment: I would call the post a red herring. It derailed the discussion from the real issue to one which I had already addressed (yes it does work). Also, I consider it "trolling" to nit-pick the only other commenter until they leave. Call it what you will, I find it distracting and unhelpful.

Comment: @spinlock `it derailed the discussion from the real issue` you keep using really strong, pointed language and blowing the issue out of proportion.  I don't understand why you can't see that some people make mistakes, and that you made several: you didn't understand how our moderation tools are used, you didn't provide additional details for your question, and you mis-read a person's status as as mod to mean they were abusing their power. Making mistakes is ok, but you took it too far.

Comment: @spinlock You're correct, it did derail the discussion.  Of course, it didn't do so intentionally; it did so because the question was unclear (to that user).  In response to an answer that misunderstands the question you could have clarified the question, immediately moving the discussion back on track.  You choose not to do so (and still haven't done so), thereby giving both the answerer, and other readers, reason to believe that it was the correct interpretation of your question.